# Zooming Vertically Through a DatagridView

Tags: c#, winforms

There is a functionality I was dreaming of implementing one day, and that day is today.
I have a datagrid with hundreds of lines and my client doesn't even want to hear about paging (special use case). So I would like to be able to **resize all rows AND content (text) with a "magnifying glass +/- " tool that affects the height of all rows in my DGV** and also the Font of the text in it.
There are many ways to perform this and I wanted to ask what was a convenient and advisable way to do this (As I am more of a server-side than GUI oriented developer)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to use **WPF** ..

Refer to the following link:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ivo_manolov/archive/2007/10/05/ui-scaling-ui-zooming-with-wpf.aspx

---

You can use host **WPF** controls in **windows-based** applications.

Refer to the following links ..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742215.aspx

[WPF control in windows forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759345/wpf-control-in-windows-forms)

http://www.programmerfish.com/how-to-add-wpf-controls-in-simple-windows-forms/

http://blogs.infragistics.com/wpf/articles/hosting-a-wpf-control-in-a-windows-forms-application.aspx

Comment: But my project is winforms-based. Is is possible to mix winforms and WPF in some way? I have to admit that all this XAML stuff frankly repels me...

Comment: Very interesting indeed. Though I was hoping for an "easy" way to do it in winforms. Guess I'll have to progressively rewrite all my GUI stuff in WPF in that case. I'll give it a look and try it out.